# Convert path to query string variable using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, url-rewriting, expression

I am trying to make Apache send:
`http://mydomain.com/these/are/arguments/mmmk`

to:
`http://mydomain.com/?pages=these/are/arguments/mmmk`

Such that `$_GET['pages']` will display `these/are/arguments/mmmk`.

I have set 'AllowEncodedSlashes' to On.

The rule needs to be able to handle trailing slashes, and when there is no subpages (like `http://mydomain.com`)

Does anyone know how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to not rewrite images/scripts you'll need to make sure the file or directory does not exist first in your .htaccess file

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # Rewrite everything else through the pages parameter 
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?pages=$1 [L]
```