# Add extension to all urls on my site

Tags: php

I created a site in Wordpress, so many of the menus and links are managed by the CMS. The site has several version, depending on a variable (or townid) that is selected and saved as a cookie. For example:

```
if($townname='Smallville') { $townid = 12; }
```

In the example above, if you visit a page, and the townid is 12, you will see content relevant to Smallville. The problem is, when someone shares a link to facebook, they share the regular link, and not the variable.  So, they will share www.site.com/page1, but not the town variable. I need them to share www.site.com/page1?townid=12.

I cant go into all the links and change them (the site is very large). Plus, the menu's are managed by the CMS, and wont allow for multiple links depending on a variable (not easily, anyway).

Does someone know how I can do this? I'm not a huge programmer, so any help is appreciated.

Note: The townid variable will not always be 12, so just doing a rewrite with the htaccess file wont work (unless there is a way to call the php varible into the htaccess file).

Comment: Why is it that when they copy the url, they don't get the variable. Shouldn't the URL bar be reading www.site.com/page1?townid=12 ?

Comment: While the above question in comment is valid, I would also like to add that other sites such as youtube simply generate the sharable URL's. So somewhere in your site you can also have a section to share this page in facebook, youtube whatever, and then generate the URLs appropriately. This way you can also read cookie values and and customize your URL however you like.

Comment: @Goose - Because the php variable is saved as a cookie, and hidden in the code (and not directly in the URL). I didn't think this was an issue when the site was created, but now it is (so I can't go back and change all the URLs).

Comment: @Rash - As for shareable links... that is an option, but will only work if they share my site via one of my own share links (not if they sharing using a browser widget, or if they user just copy and paste the link)

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to do some url rewriting, but dynamically, in order to construct the query from the cookie that holds the townid. [here (urls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234479/convert-path-to-query-string-variable-using-mod-rewrite) and [here (cookies)](https://serverfault.com/questions/499246/how-do-i-make-rewritecond-http-cookie-match-a-cookie-value-exactly)

In this case I'd suggest using a rewrite rule such as the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}     townid=([^;]+) 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$             /$1?townId=%1  [L]
```

Which will allow you to use urls of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/page1
```

Provided a cookie value is provided with the key `townId`

Note that cookie values are also not copied with the url when it is shared; presumably there is a way of detecting this for new visitors to the site?

Comment: This rewrites a URL that already has the variable in the URL. My townid variable is saved as a cookie, and not in the URL ... I basically need to go from www.site.com to www.site.com/?townid=12 (based on the townid in the cookie)

Comment: Useful information, that the townId will be included in a cookie - I've edited my answer to incorporate this.

Comment: I'll try this out! Thanks!

Comment: Tried it, and nothing happened. If I click any URL, the browser just takes me to that URL (and does not add the new "townid" information to the URL). My first concern: how does the htaccess file know which cookie it is pulling information (since the cookie name "towns" is not declared)?

Comment: That's part of the "RewriteCond" line - 'townid=<anything>' is what the code after %{HTTP_COOKIE} is looking for. If the user visiting the site doesn't have a cookie with the label 'townid' set, then no url rewriting will occur.

Comment: My site has a cookie with a townid variable, and the rewrite isn't occurring...   :(